# how to re-initialize java servlet on text file change

Tags: java, servlets, cron, reload

I have a servlet that pulls data from a text file during initialization. 
Now I am updating that text file with a cron job(say everyday at 10am) and want to reinitialize the servlet every time this particular file changes.

Second approach I can follow is to sync the reinitialization of the servlet to my cron job.

Kindly suggest on how to go about implementing either of the above two approaches.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't get hold of it as instance variable of the servlet. Create a [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) which stores it in the application scope and runs a thread which updates it on every interval with help of [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

E.g.

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        Data data = new Data(); // Your class which reads and holds data upon construction.
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("data", data);
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Reloader(data), 0, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }

}
```

with this runnable

```
public class Reloader implements Runnable {

    private Data data;

    public Reloader(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        data.reload();
    }

}
```

It's accessible a random servlet.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Data data = (Data) getServletContext().getAttribute("data");
    // ...
}
```

And even in a random JSP.

```
${data.something}
```

Comment: Do it all for him why don't cha' :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. And I really appreciate the example.

Comment: I would like to ask, how do it implement these code in my eclipse project? I added the 2 new class, but eclipse complains that the reload() method doesn't exist.

Comment: The answer sounds great and I wish to use it, but where is ServletContextListener being used from? I am using the Tomcat7 server runtime libraries and i only see ServletContexthandler and that annotation does not exist in my case. You did not mention any libraries to reference.

Comment: Actually I just found it, I was typing in eclipse 'extends' instead of 'implements' and it was only showing me non-interface classes in the auto-complete. My error.

Answer (score 1):

Have your servlet occasionally check the file for changes with a timer.

Googling "Java monitor file for changes" will present many examples, one of which you can find here: http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/jforum/src/net/jforum/util/FileMonitor.java.shtml